# drawText causing problems when scrolling in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am having a Custom Text box that shows the count of the characters at the right corner of the Textbox.
I have done so by Inheriting the QTextEdit and overriding the paint event and using QPainter to paint the character count.

The problem is that when scrolling the painting is distorted and multiple character counts are shown. The problem can be seen more clearly when using the scrollbar to scroll instead of the mouse wheel.

Here is my code.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class TextBox(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, maxChar=1000, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TextBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.charCount = 0
        self.maxChar = maxChar

        self.painter_font = self.font()
        self.painter_font.setFamily('')
        self.painter_font.setPointSize(5)

        self.textChanged.connect(self.changeCount)

    def changeCount(self):
        self.charCount = len(self.toPlainText())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        if self.charCount < self.maxChar:
            super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

        if self.charCount >= self.maxChar:
            if event.key() in [QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace, QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete, QtCore.Qt.Key_Up,
                               QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, QtCore.Qt.Key_Right, QtCore.Qt.Key_Down]:
                super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

            if event.key() & QtCore.Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(TextBox, self).paintEvent(event)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        painter.setFont(self.painter_font)

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
        count = f'{self.charCount}/{self.maxChar}'

        multiplier = 4
        if self.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            multiplier = 8

        painter.drawText(QtCore.QPoint(self.width() - (len(count) * multiplier + 30), self.height() - 10), count)  # This is to make sure that the count stays inside the textbox when the number increases. If you have a better way pls help.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = TextBox()
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: You could try using a label to display the count and adjust its position when a resize event occurs or when one of the scrollbars become visible.

Comment: @Heike label inside the TextEdit?

Comment: Yes, make the label a child of the TextEdit and override resizeEvent of the TextEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of how you could use a label to print the character count on your text

```
class TextBox(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, maxChar=1000, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TextBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.charCount = 0
        self.maxChar = maxChar

        self.textChanged.connect(self.changeCount)

        # add a label to self.
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('', self)
        self.label.setFixedSize(150, 15)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        palette = self.label.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.WindowText, QtGui.QColor("red"))
        self.label.setPalette(palette)
        self.changeCount()

    # the label text is updated when character count is changed   
    def changeCount(self):
        self.charCount = len(self.toPlainText())
        self.label.setText(f'{self.charCount}/{self.maxChar}')

    # The position of the label needs to be updated manually when the size of the text box changes     
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.label.move(event.size().width()-self.label.width(), event.size().height()-self.label.height())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        if self.charCount < self.maxChar:
            super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

        if self.charCount >= self.maxChar:
            if event.key() in [QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace, QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete, QtCore.Qt.Key_Up,
                               QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, QtCore.Qt.Key_Right, QtCore.Qt.Key_Down]:
                super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

            if event.key() & QtCore.Qt.Key_A and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                super(TextBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer could you also explain why the paint event was causing a problem?

Comment: Widgets don't always update all their contents, especially QAbstractScrollArea based widgets, and that's for optimization performances: they only update the parts that actually need repainting, which also includes *clearing* previous painting. In your case, the area in which the text was previously painted doesn't get *cleared*, so some portion of previous text are still visible. You can check the actual update area using the event's `rect()` or `region()`. As an alternative, you could have forced a scheduled full repaint (`self.viewport().update()`) whenever the vertical position changed.

Comment: @musicamante thx for the comment. one more question is using label better than painting the text in the textbox? (pls tag me when replying)

Comment: That's up to you, it completely depends on the situation, and you need to evaluate what's better, considering performances and simplicity of code. (tagging is not always required: in this case since you were the only commenter, you would have got the notification anyway, [as explained on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: @musicamante I didn't receive any notification including for the one you commented just now.

Comment: Then there should be some malfunction or they changed the behavior. In any case, you have read the message, so I really don't see the point of making me notice that, since you know we both know about that feature (I could've just forgot that due to further editing). Let's avoid pointless off-topic arguments in comments.